# How do I combine elements in an array matching a pattern?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, concatenation

I have an array of strings

```
["123", "a", "cc", "dddd", "mi hello", "33"]
```

I want to join by a space consecutive elements that begin with a letter, have at least two characters, and do not contain a space. Applying that logic to the above would yield

```
["123", "a", "cc dddd", "mi hello", "33"]
```

Similarly if my array were

```
["mmm", "3ss", "foo", "bar", "foo", "55"]
```

I would want the result to be

```
["mm", "3ss", "foo bar foo", "55"]
```

How do I do this operation?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this; ruby is a highly expressive language. It would be most beneficial for you to show *what you have tried so far*, so that we can help debug/fix/improve your attempt.

For example, here is one possible implementation that I came up with:

```
def combine_words(array)
  array
    .chunk {|string| string.match?(/\A[a-z][a-z0-9]+\z/i) }
    .flat_map {|concat, strings| concat ? strings.join(' ') : strings}
end

combine_words(["aa", "b", "cde", "f1g", "hi", "2j", "l3m", "op", "q r"])
  # => ["aa", "b", "cde f1g hi", "2j", "l3m op", "q r"]
```

Note that I was a little unclear exactly how to interpret your requirement:

> begin with a letter, have at least two characters, and do not contain a space

Can strings contain punctuation? Underscores? Utf-8 characters? I took it to mean "only a-z, A-Z or 0-9", but you may want to tweak this.

A literal interpretation of your requirement could be: `/\A[[:alpha:]][^ ]+\z/`, but I suspect that's not what you meant.

**Explanation:**

- [`Enumerable#chunk`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) will iterate through the array and collect terms by the block's response value. In this case, it will find sequential elements that match/don't match the required regex.
- [`String#match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-match-3F) checks whether the string matches the pattern, and returns a boolean response. Note that if you were using ruby `v2.3` or below, you'd have needed some workaround such as `!!string.match`, to force a boolean response.
- [`Enumerable#flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) then loops through each "result", joining the strings if necessary, and flattens the result to avoid returning any nested arrays.

---

Here is another, similar, solution:

```
def word?(string)
  string.match?(/\A[a-z][a-z0-9]+\z/i)
end

def combine_words(array)
  array
    .chunk_while {|x, y| word?(x) && word?(y)}
    .map {|group| group.join(' ')}
end
```

Or, here's a more "low-tech" solution - which only uses more basic language features. (I'm re-using the same `word?` method here):

```
def combine_words(array)
  previous_was_word = false
  result = []
  array.each do |string|
    if previous_was_word && word?(string)
      result.last << " #{string}"
    else
      result << string
    end
    previous_was_word = word?(string)
  end
  result
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk).

```
def chunk_it(arr)    
  arr.chunk { |s|
    (s.size > 1) && (s[0].match?(/\p{Alpha}/)) && !s.include?(' ')}.
      flat_map { |tf,a| tf ? a.join(' ') : a }
end

chunk_it(["123", "a", "cc", "dddd", "mi hello", "33"])
  #=> ["123", "a", "cc dddd", "mi hello", "33"]
chunk_it ["mmm", "3ss", "foo", "bar", "foo", "55"]
```